# Enumerate Package

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to write an exam paper using LaTeX. I use the enumerate package, e.g.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This question is about balloons.
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item What shape are balloons?
      \item What colour are balloons?
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

The problem comes from when I want to put commentary into the question. At the moment, the first level of enumerate gives me a number, and the second a letter. But in between the letters, I might like to say something about the next part of the question, and I would like that outdented, i.e. not on the same level as the lettered parts of the question. I have a work around:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This question is about balloons.
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
      \item What shape are balloons?
    \end{enumerate}
  Assume that all balloons are the same shape.
    \begin{enumerate}[(b)]
      \item What colour are balloons?
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

This is a real pain in the you-know-what. Doing it this way, everything in the last enumerate environment gets labelled as `(b)`. So I have to `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}`  and label every subsequent part:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This question is about balloons.
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
      \item What shape are balloons?
    \end{enumerate}
  Assume that all balloons are the same shape.
    \begin{enumerate}[(b)]
      \item What colour are balloons?
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[(c)]
      \item Why do I have to keep doing this?
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}[(d)]
      \item Why do I have to keep doing this?
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: You should consider the `enumitem` package, instead, and its `resume` feature.

Comment: @egreg Sounds promising. How do I get this package? How do I use this package? Do you know of a link to user-friendly instructions?

Comment: `enumitem` is included in both MikTeX and TeX Live, so you may have it already. If not, which TeX distribution do you have?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm using TeXnicCenter. I added `usepackage{enumitem}` and it opened a Package Installation window. I've downloaded the style file, but I'm not sure how to install it. (I have folders called MikTeX, so I assume I have MikTeX)

Comment: `enumerate` is quite old and you should probably use `enumitem` but you can use `enumerate` but you are misusing it `\begin{enumerate}[(b)]` should be `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]\setcounter{enumii}{2}` Only `a` is a special value to set the counter format you can not use `b` to set the start value.

Comment: TeXnicCenter is just the editor, and doesn't really have anything to do with installing packages -- the distribution (in this case MikTeX) takes care of that. Anyways, MikTeX has a package manager, you can find a shortcut in the start menu. In that, you can search for, and install, packages. Or, if you have activated on-the-fly installation of missing packages, all you have to do is compile a document with `\usepackage{enumitem}`, and the installation happens automatically.

Comment: (Heh, I didn't read your comment to the end, silly me.) If you dis as asked in the installation window, then the package should be installed. Does the document compile?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I played about with it for a bit and found an option to let me download missing packages from the internet. Then I chose a mirror from a British University. I clicked that, restarted LaTeX, and it compiled. (With 14 errors!) I've fixed all the errors now, and am fully converted to `enumitem`. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks David. I've taken your advice and got myself using `enumitem`. I first learned to use LaTeX in 2002, and have stuck to what I was taught ever since. I'm quite fluent at type setting, but a total novice when it comes to anything else.

Comment: there is a dedicated [exam document class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) that facilitates exams beautifully- highly recommend it

Comment: @cmhughes This looks very interesting. I don't know how to install a `.cls` file. I changed the document class of a working file to `{exam}` and tried to compile. I got a package install window pop-up. I asked it to install via the web like I had when I got `enumitem.sty` but that didn't work. I've downloaded `exam.cls` but don't know how it install it.

Comment: @FlybyNight; that depends on the editor you use. Most times though you can simply search on the computer in which map the other `.cls` files are, and place it there. After that you have to update the `file name database`. How that is done depends on the editor, but you should be able to easily find it online.

Comment: @Mythio I'm using TeXnicCenter. I have no idea what a map is, or a file name database. Sorry.

Comment: Texnicenter uses miktex so you can use the instructions in the answer provided here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows

Comment: @Mythio Thanks for trying to help, but I have no idea what a local tree structure is. I don't even know where the folders are. I have three folders containing MikTeX stuff, and they all expand to contain 30 folders each. I was hoping there might be a way to do it via the in-editor menus.

Comment: @Mythio p.s. to make it worse, Windows 8 doesn't even have a start button, so I can't update the database in the way the link suggests :'(

Comment: Hmm sorry man, I don't know texniccenter well enough to know if it can be done from the editor. I suggest posting a new question asking for steps to install a `.cls` file on windows 8 with texniccenter. That will probably get you the help you need :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is quite easy with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{subquestion}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[subquestion,1]{label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item This question is about balloons.
   \begin{subquestion}
   \item What shape are balloons?
   \end{subquestion}
Assume that all balloons are the same shape.
  \begin{subquestion}[resume]
  \item What colour are balloons?
  \item Why do I have to keep doing this?
  \end{subquestion}
Something else.
  \begin{subquestion}[resume]
  \item Why do I have to keep doing this?
  \end{subquestion}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]